# How to read new form value input in javascript while database generated variable is in input form value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following:

1a) form.php: html form input field where I let the user update its account details:

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>">
```

Note: php $first_name variable has a database generated value

1b) form.php: making a javascript var to get the input value

```
var firstname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
```

2) form.js:

```
$('.account-details input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    //validation code
    if(firstname === ""){
       //code here
    }
    //etc ... other validation code
}
```

Note: I use scr to link form.js to form.php

```
<script src="js/form.js"></script>
```

Question: How can I get the new value that the user puts in and not the value from the database I echoed out?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if a user add a new value to the input it will override the one you echoed

Comment: @LGSon For some reason it doesn't.

Comment: As this fiddle work, [https://jsfiddle.net/zdtqy65u/](https://jsfiddle.net/zdtqy65u/), you need to post yours reproducing the issue not work

Comment: @LGSon I found the error. It happened to be a scope problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to grab the value via JavaScript and send it via AJAX to an external PHP page that'll run your database INSERT query using that value as POST or GET variable. This is one way to do it

```
var firstname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "modifyuser.php",     //Your php page
                data: "firstname="+ firstname,     // pass data
                success: function(response){
                    $('#output').html(response);
                }
            });
        return false;

    }
    //etc ... other validation code
}
```

php page

```
<?php
// your connect etc etc
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

mysql query to insert data

echo "SUCCESS";
```

?>